# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: MainData

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use a sqlite3 database in python but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Proyecto\Src_School_Admin\SchoolAdmin-Director.py", line 4, in <module>
    from execute_files.Sqlitedb import FirstUseInfo
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Proyecto\Src_School_Admin\execute_files\Sqlitedb.py", line 17, in <module>
    FirstUseInfo()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Proyecto\Src_School_Admin\execute_files\Sqlitedb.py", line 12, in FirstUseInfo
    s = cursor.execute("SELECT Use FROM MainData")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: MainData
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

The `FirstUseInfo` function is located in a file in the following path:`C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Project\Src_School_Admin\execute_files` together with the database

and the file that sends to call the `FirstUseInfo` function is in`C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Project\Src_School_Admin`

but it does not work keeps marking the error

**First.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from execute_files.Sqlitedb import FirstUseInfo

class InitWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #uic.loadUi("UIX/first.ui",self)

        #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.LStatus.setText("Cargando...")

        self.FirstUse()
        FirstUseInfo()

    def FirstUse(self):
        pass


app = QApplication([])
iw = InitWindow()
iw.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Sqlitedb.py**

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import os

def FirstUseInfo():
    r = str(os.getcwd())
    final = r.replace("\\","/")
    result = None
    d=final+"/InfoDB.db"

    conexion = sqlite3.connect(d)
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    s = cursor.execute("SELECT Use FROM MainData")
    for i in s:
        result = int(i[0])
    return print(result)
    conexion.close()
FirstUseInfo()
```

if I run `FirstUseInfo ()` from `Sqlitedb.py` there is no problem but if I execute it from another side it throws the error.

[image]

I realized that for some reason another database is created in the directory `C: \ Users \ Angel \ Desktop \ Project \ Src_School_Admin`, which is where the file that sends to call the`FirstUseInfo` function is located

Comment: Did you create the table first?

Comment: @KlausD,if the table is created

Comment: This code looks in the current working directory for the database file.  Is your current directory the same in all the cases?

Answer (score 0):

> but if I execute it from another side it throws the error.

So your code

```
r = str(os.getcwd())
final = r.replace("\\","/")
result = None
d=final+"/InfoDB.db"
```

gives new filename every time you are running program from somewhere else.
When you run 
`conexion = sqlite3.connect(d)` 
SQLite doesn't see the database and it creates there.

You should make some variable where you will store real filename for your database file.

Answer (score 0):

solve it by attaching this line of code

`r = os.path.dirname (__ file __)`

`source = r.replace ('\\'," / ") +" / InfoDB.db "`
as I understand this line returns the absolute value of the location of the file